# Hibernate how to delete objects in a set?

Tags: hibernate

I have an object User (has id, username, password) that has a set of UserRoles (has id, username, userrole).

The way things are mapped, the UserRole table looks like this:

```
USER_ROLE
id
username
userrole
userid
```

When a user gets a higher role, say from "general" to "admin", replace the set of role with a new set of roles like so:

```
User u = userService.findById(userId);
Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
roles.set(new UserRole(u.getUsername(), "ADMIN");
userService.update(u);
```

In the end I want there to be one role for the user, but there's two in the database.  One "GENERAL" with userId = null, and one "ADMIN" with the correct userId.

Any idea what I need to do so the first role gets deleted instead of having userId set to null?

Need help, thanks!
rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want these roles to be deleted from the database when they are removed from the collection, you need to map the collection with `orphanRemoval = true` (for JPA 2.0 annotations) or with `DELETE_ORPHAN` cascading option (for XML or pre-3.5 versions of Hibernate).

Though in that case you can't simply replace the collection, you need to clear the existing collection with its methods, such as `clear()`.

**See also:**

- [11.11. Transitive persistence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive)

Comment: Setting cascade="all-delete-orphan" and clearing the existing collection seems to have worked.  Thanks!